# Jenkins Groovyshell with build step

Tags: jenkins, groovy, groovyshell

I want to execute code which is written(and generated) as string
I made .Jenkinsfile file:

```
    pipeline {
        stages {
            stage('validation') {
                steps{
                    script{
                        new GroovyShell().evaluate("""build (job:'myjob' , parameters:[string(name: 'FOO', value: "BAR")]""")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And I receive error:

```
    hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.string() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[name:FOO, value:BAR]]
Possible solutions: toString(), toString(), print(java.lang.Object), print(java.io.PrintWriter), print(java.lang.Object), run()
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:80)
```

I do not need to use exactly GroovyShell, any variant of executing string will be appropriate for me

Answer (score 0):

You can move your script to a file like below and then use the `load` method the read and execute it.

**test.groovy**

```
def call() {
    echo "Running the Job"
    build (job:'myjob' , parameters:[string(name: 'FOO', value: "BAR")])
}

return this;
```

**Pipeline**

```
script{
    def exec = load "PATH/TO/SCRIPT/test.groovy"
    exec()
}
```